# Check to see if exception and system logging enabled

Tags: log

I want to programmaticly discover if the Magento exception log and system log are enabled.  In what config file would I look?  For what value?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can get if the log is enabled like this:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('dev/log/active');
```

If you get `1` then the log is enabled.
As a side note...
if you want to force a log even if the logging is not enabled you can do this:

```
Mage::log('Message to log', null, 'file_to_log.log', true);
```

The 4th parameter `true`, makes magento not care if the log is enabled or not. It will log anyway.

Comment: But what is the config file that stores that information.  I just want to grep it from the config file.

Comment: @menders65. There is no config file. The config in magento is composed of various things. It might be a file but it might be a db entry. See here how the config is composed: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/29839/146

Comment: normally log appears in `var/log/system.log` or `var/log/exception.log`