# Mage::getStoreConfig functionality question

Tags: magento-1.8, configuration, overrides, controllers

I have a controller rewrite (working fine) that rewrites the customer login action.

It's just an exercise, and I'm trying to automatically direct the user to the men's section of the store immediately upon login.

In the module's config (the one rewriting the controller), I have the following section:

```
<default>
    <customer_rewrite>
        <customer>
            <target_category_id>16</target_category_id>
        </customer>
    </customer_rewrite>
</default>
```

The overwritten login controller looks like this:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    parent::loginAction();

    $categoryId = Mage::getStoreConfig('customer_rewrite/customer/target_category_id');
    // Do more stuff here...
}
```

My question is this: When using Mage::getStoreConfig(), how does Magento know which config.xml to look in? Does it parse through all of them to find my unique node, or does it somehow get told which module's config to use?

Comment: take a look at this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/29839/146

Comment: Thanks Marius, that definitely cleared it up for me substantially. In my mind (and I might be misunderstanding here) it is directly opposite of how redirection would work. ([see my question about setBeforeAuthUrl and setAfterAuthUrl here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112697/setbeforeauthurl-and-setafterauthurl))

Answer (score 2):

Magento have a table named `core_config_data` which structure is like this:
[image]

In this table magento store all value of `system.xml` defined path.

Like for `category root id`  it store `catalog/category/root_id` as a path.

Comment: Thanks Asish, but I already know about the core_config_data table, my question is more with regards to reading XML configs, and not the configs in the DB :)