# setBeforeAuthUrl and setAfterAuthUrl

Tags: magento-1.8, url-rewrite

I have rewritten the customer login function to immediately redirect the customer to a specific category.

The overwritten login function looks like this:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    parent::loginAction();

    $categoryId = Mage::getStoreConfig('customer_rewrite/customer/target_category_id');
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $url = $this->_getSeoCategoryUrl($categoryId, $storeId);
    $this->_getSession()->setBeforeAuthUrl($url);
}
```

This function works perfectly (`_getSeoCategoryUrl` is a protected function I wrote to create the relevant URL, and is not important for this question, I think) and redirects to the correct category page.

I'm just curious why I had to use setBeforeAuthUrl, and not setAfterAuthUrl - I would like to know why I have to do it like that, since using setAfterAuthUrl results in the user just ending on the usual login landing page.

Any clarification on this would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find your answer looking the code in the controller you've rewritten

Take a look at method `_loginPostRedirect()`, there you'll see how Magento manages both variables, and, at the end...

```
 $this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));
```

Comment: Short, concise, clear. I like it!

Comment: Glad it helped ;)